# gulp sass not writing to destination directory

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I've started using the gulp-sass 5.
It's behaviour seems different from gulp-sass 4, requiring different configuration.

I've managed to figure out how to get it reading scss files.
But I can't figure out how to get it to write them.

With the following config, no files are written to the './css' directory.

```
  function buildStyles() {
        return gulp.src('./sass/**.scss')
            .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
    };
```

How can I get sass to actually write the files?

Answer (score 1):

You should define a `task` for compile `sass files`
See here
: [Gulp Sass](https://zetcode.com/gulp/sass/)

gulpfile.js

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const del = require('del');

gulp.task('styles', () => {
    return gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});

gulp.task('clean', () => {
    return del([
        'css/main.css',
    ]);
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(['clean', 'styles']));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, By looking inside `gulp-sass` code, I figured out it's because the source file name starts with `_`

```
if (path.basename(file.path).startsWith('_')) {
  callback();
  return;
}
// ^ inside gulp-sass core js file
```

I'm not sure what purpose this serves but it seems like it was made intentionally to ignore files starting with `_`, renaming the files fixed it for me